# Bash extract lines from text file and add additional columns containing variable

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have 2 variables, i and j. For each combination of the variables, there is a text file, text.txt, with text arranged in space-separated columns, e.g.:

```
string1 43245 7.45
string2 23452 9.34
string3 23652 2.57
```

I would like to do the following:
Make one large text file containing all text files with the variables added in additional columns, and some other additional columns containing text, not from variables.
E.g.

```
i = x01
j = y01
```

Then the output should be:

```
x01 y01 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x01 y01 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x01 y01 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
```

I have tried something like:

```
awk '{$0="'"$i"' '"$j"' extrastring"$0}'1 $i/$j/text.txt >> newtext.txt
```

That doesn't work.

Edit:
I probably need to add that this should run in a double for loop:

```
for i in x01 x02 x03
do
    for j in y01 y02 y03
    do
    awk '{$0="'"$i"' '"$j"' extrastring"$0}'1 $i/$j/text.txt >> newtext.txt
    done
done
```

Edit:
I tried this based on SoFan's answer

```
for i in x01 x02 x03
do
    for j in y01 y02 y03
    do
    cd $i/$j/
    awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '{print i,j,"extrastring",$0}' text.txt >> newtext.txt
    done
done
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The script won't run.

Comment: So is `test.txt` constant and you want to print it with different columns for every pair of x01.. y01..?

Comment: Sorry, no the text file is not constant. There is a different text.txt in every $i/$j/ - folder, e.g. x01/y01/text.txt, x01/y02/text.txt, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v i="x01" -v j="y01" '{print i,j,"extrastring",$0}' text.txt
x01 y01 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x01 y01 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x01 y01 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
```

Or if you have already declared variable :

```
i=x01
j=y01
awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '{print i,j,"extrastring",$0}' text.txt
```

Comment: This looks right, but it won't work. Can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

How about using [the `read` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) to read the files, and output using `echo`?

Something like

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do
    echo "$i $j extrastring $line"
done > newfile.txt
```

Comment: cat not really needed !?!

Answer (score 0):

Version 3:

```
for var1 in x01 x02
do 
    for var2 in y01 y02
    do 
        awk '{ print "'"$var1 $var2"'" " extrastring " $0}' $var1/$var2/text.txt
    done
done
x01 y01 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x01 y01 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x01 y01 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
x01 y02 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x01 y02 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x01 y02 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
x02 y01 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x02 y01 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x02 y01 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
x02 y02 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
x02 y02 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
x02 y02 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
```

Didn't test it under directory structure, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
dataFile=$1
varFile=$2
line=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' $varFile | tr '\n' ' ')
awk -v variables="${line}" '{print variables "extrastring " $0 }' $dataFile


user@host:/tmp$ cat dataFile 
string1 43245 7.45
string2 23452 9.34
string3 23652 2.57

user@host:/tmp$ cat varFile 
i = x01
j = y01

user@host:/tmp$ ./test.sh dataFile varFile 
 x01  y01 extrastring string1 43245 7.45
 x01  y01 extrastring string2 23452 9.34
 x01  y01 extrastring string3 23652 2.57
```